# How are HtmlHelper image references determined in CakePHP for a plugin?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Still new to this cakePHP framework and having trouble grasping how the helper urls are created when using a plugin. Using cakePHP 1.3.12, most of the link references are getting the proper plugin name, however, when trying to reference images, this is failing.

For example, take the following folder structure:

```
/app/webroot/img/
/app/plugins/myPluginName/:
                         /controllers/checkout
                         /webroot/img/add_item.png
                          :
```

In the view the following snippet is added:

```
$this->Html->link( $this->Html->image("add_item.png"),
                   array('controller' => 'checkout', 'action' => 'index'),
                   array('escape' => false)
);
```

When this renders I get:

```
<a href="/myPluginName/checkout"><img src="/img/add_item.png" /></a>
```

This breaks the image as the location should be /myPluginName/img/add_item.png. Is there a way to get the image to reference properly without having to hard code in the full path?

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to put the plugin in the path like:

```
$this->Html->link($this->Html->image('/myPluginName/img/add_item.png'),
array('controller' => 'checkout', 'action' => 'index'),
array('escape' => false));
```

CakePHP Manual as remarked: "It is important to note the /your_plugin/ prefix before the img, js or css path. That makes the magic happen!"

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1117/Plugin-assets